# NDB Put Transactions are being Overwritten

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a dictionary that I would like to write in whole to an NDB on App Engine.  The problem is that only the last item in the dictionary is being written.  I thought perhaps the writes were too fast so I put a sleep timer in with a very long wait of 20 seconds to see what would happen.  I continually refreshed the Datastore Viewer and saw the transaction write, and then later get overwritten by the next transaction, etc.  The table started out empty and the dictionary keys are unique.  A simple example:

```
class Stats(ndb.Model):
    desc= ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    count= ndb.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    update = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)    

class refresh(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):

      statsStore = Stats()

      dict = {"test1":0,"test2":1,"test3":2}

      for key in dict:
         statsStore.desc = key
         statsStore.count = dict.get(key)
         statsStore.put()
```

What will happen above is that only the final dictionary item will remain in the datastore.  Again with a sleep timer I can see each being written but then overwritten. I am using this on my local machine with the local development GAE environment.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I seemed to have solved the problem.  Instead of referring to the fields separately as in the for loop above, I wrote it like this: statsStore=Stats(desc=key,count=dict.get(key)).  Not 100% sure why this was the correct way so still appreciate some edification.

Comment: A slightly more Pythonic way to do the loop is `for key, value in dict.items()` then use `statsStore.count = value`.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel.  That is a the better way to structure that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that you're reusing the same entity (model instance).

During the first put(), a datastore key is generated and assigned to that entity. Then, all the following put() calls are using the same key.

Changing it to create a new model instance on each iteration (the solution you mention in your comment) will ensure a new datastore key is generated each time.

Another option would be to clear the key with "statsStore.key = None" before calling put(). But what you did is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but here are some hopefully helpful pointers. If you want to save the dict and then re-use it later by reading from the database, then change your string to a text property, import json, and save the dict as a json string value using json.dumps(). If you want to write an entity for every element in your dict, then you will want to move your statsStore class creation line inside the for loop, and finish the loop process by adding each Stats() classes to an array. Once the loop is done, you can batch put all the entities in the array. This batch approach is much faster than including a put() inside your loop which is most often a very non-performant design choice. If you just want to record all the values in the dict for later reference, and you have a value that you can safely use as a delimiter, then I would create two empty arrays prior to your loop, and append each desc and count inside the respective array. Once outside the array, you can save these values to two text properties in your entity by joining the arrays using the delimiter string. If you do this, then strongly suggest using urllib.quote() to escape your desc text value when appending it so at to avoid conflicts with your delimiter value.

Some final notese: You should be careful using this type of process with a StringProperty. You might easily exceed the string limit size depending on the number of items, and/or the length of your desc values. Also remember your items in the dict may not come out in the order you intend. Consider something like: "for k, v in sorted(mydict.items()):" HTH, stevep